# How to display dynamicaly a date time to a locale format with moment?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs, locale

I display the day and time of the visitor depending on what `locale` and `timezone` he chose.
Everything works fine, but with my code the format is always the same.

I'd like to apply a dynamic format with the day, the month, the year and time according to the format of the locale selected.

Is this possible ?

Here is my custom hook :

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import IntlStorage from "../helpers/IntlStorage";

export const useLocaleTime = () => {
    const [formattedTime, setFormattedTime] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const locale = IntlStorage.getLocale(); // en-US for example
    const timezone = IntlStorage.getTimezone(); // US/Alaska for example

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateTime = () => {
            moment.locale(locale);
            moment.tz.setDefault(timezone);

            const currentTime = moment().format("D MMMM YYYY LTS");

            setFormattedTime(currentTime);
        };

        const interval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [locale, timezone]);

    return formattedTime;
};
```

Here is another try but does not change the return format :

```
useEffect(() => {
        const updateTime = () => {
            const options: any = {
                day: "numeric",
                month: "long",
                year: "numeric",
                hour: "numeric",
                minute: "numeric",
                second: "numeric",
                timeZone: timezone,
            };

            const currentDate = new Date();
            const formattedTime = currentDate.toLocaleString(locale, options);

            setFormattedTime(formattedTime);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about excatly what you are asking, but try the below code if thats what you want the result should be

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const localdate = new Date();
    const formatting = localdate.toLocaleString();
    const formatted = moment(formatting).format("D MMMM YYYY LTS");
    setFormattedTime(formatted);
  }, []);
```

output

```
27 December 2022 7:33:44 PM
```

Comment: `.format("D MMMM YYYY LTS");` this is the problem. I dont want to set it manualy as a string. I would like it to be dynamic. Every country has its own way to write the date. Some put years before, some puts day before. I want my date to "adapt" to the country format